# Pop old viewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

So I have 3 view controllers (and a nav view controller). Starting at VC1 I push to VC2 then when the scene for VC2 is done I pop VC2 then push to VC3. Only problem with that is that the user can see the stack push/popping. Is there anyway I can push VC3 then pop VC2 without it being noted? I know it's a stack so you can't necessarily pick elements as you can arrays, but maybe there is a way I can pop VC2 from VC3?

I saw a few stackoverflow resources but all in old syntax from 2011-2014 and are very outdated. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Leave VC2 in place and just push VC3. But when you want to leave VC3, pop to VC1. You get the same desired effect.

Comment: BTW - solutions from 2011-2014 are still valid. Just convert to Swift 3 as needed.

Comment: I would do that. But I need to dismiss the scene presented in VC2 as well. When I posted this 10 minutes ago it seemed to work but now that I have the volume up, it doesn't. Should I just do: self.viewcontroller?.presentScene(nil) then push to VC3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use the `setViewControllers:animated:` method. Like this:

```
navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc1, vc3], animated: true)
```

This will animate a push while removing the `vc2` from the stack and replacing it with `vc3`. More info about the method [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers?language=objc).

### Update:

If you don't have a reference to `vc1` in `v2` (and you probably don't) you can do this:

```
navigationController?.setViewControllers(navigationController!.viewControllers.first!, vc3], animated: true)
```

Oh, and if you wish to push `vc3` without any animation then, obviously, just call the method with `animated: false`.